# initializationError while running Junit test case

Tags: java, junit, powermock

I am running test case using Junit4 test case using PowerMockito. I have seen similar questions and their solutions didn't work- 
I have included all required jars which other solutions mentioned.

Stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:47)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassWriter(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl.isProxy(ProxyFrameworkImpl.java:29)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnmockedType(WhiteboxImpl.java:1783)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getType(WhiteboxImpl.java:2237)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.checkArgumentTypesMatchParameterTypes(WhiteboxImpl.java:2191)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:938)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:882)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:859)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:75)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:37)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.internal.impl.JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit3TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:46)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit3.PowerMockSuite.<init>(PowerMockSuite.java:39)
    at com.kronos.wfc.absencemgmt.attendance.api.config.APIWATProfileBeanMicroTest.suite(APIWATProfileBeanMicroTest.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.SuiteMethod.testFromSuiteMethod(SuiteMethod.java:35)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.SuiteMethod.<init>(SuiteMethod.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.SuiteMethodBuilder.runnerForClass(SuiteMethodBuilder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V"  typically indicate a version mis match between jars.  Could check if all jars are on appropriate versions

Comment: @Jayan : How do I verify that?